# Easily implementing Redis from mySQL with django

Tags: mysql, django, redis

I have a mySQL library and my app's views constantly make changes to mySQL.  It would be much easier for my operations to be stored in a ram cache until the user logs out, then write the info to the db to recall later.

How easy is it, and what is the best method for implementing Redis to speed up my site?

Comment: Redis caches it's data in memory but also saves it to disk, so if you use redis you might not need to use mysql. Remember most people don't explicitly logout of a website so you may not get a signal to save your data to the mysql db

Comment: @e4c5 Does redis do this simultaneously?  Say my user terminates their session (and the redis session) without saving would redis be synchronizing in memory simultaneously?

Comment: If you are asking if redis automatically saves things to disk (while also keeping a copy in memory) the answer is yes. http://oldblog.antirez.com/post/redis-persistence-demystified.html